# Do I need to notify Irish authorities when I leave on a working holiday?

Tags: canada, ireland, working-holiday

I'm leaving Ireland and I'm going to Canada on a 2 year working holiday.

Should I notify any Irish authorities of this?  e.g. Revenue for tax issues?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need to do that at least no in China I do not know policies in Ireland. Make sure you check with someone more crediable.